# Hide border-top attribute for dynamically generated <td>

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal react component that renders a table that iterates through an array of users/emails (waitList) and displays them in a  tag. My goal is to only remove the first border-top attribute in the row (see image).

[image: an image of my table and which border i want removed]

Here's a snippet of my component in case my description wasn't clear-

```
  renderTableRows() {
    const iter = [];
    if (this.props.waitList !== null) {
      this.props.waitList.map(applicant => {
        iter.push(
          <tr>
            <td>{applicant.user.name}</td>
            <td>{applicant.user.email}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      });
    }
    return iter;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal show={this.state.waitListModalIsOpen}>
          <Modal.Header>
            WAIT LIST ({this.props.waitListCount})
          </ Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <table className={'table wait-list-table'}>
              <tbody>
                {this.renderTableRows()}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </ Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={() => { this.closeWaitListModal(); }}>Cancel</Button>
          </ Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I understand that because I am iterating each `td` here that nth-child will remove all borders for the supplied child parameter, rather than just the first in the list. Is there a way I can hide this border using CSS? If not, recommendations for how to improve my iteration logic in my React component is welcomed.

Comment: Does :first-child not work?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner - :first-child will hide the border-top attribute for all user names, rather than just the first row.

Comment: Even if you put it on the `tbody` class?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner unfortunately no - because that style is on the <td>, not the <tr> element

Comment: @colincr Check my answer below

Comment: Is the border on tr or td?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
table tr td {border-top: solid gray 1px; }
table tr:first-child td {border-top: none;}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>aa</td>
<td>bb</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>aaa</td>
<td>bbb</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along the lines of this:

JS:

```
renderTableRows() {
const iter = [];

if (this.props.waitList !== null) {
  this.props.waitList.map((applicant, index) => {
    iter.push(
      <tr>
        <td className={index === 0 ? "no-border-top" : ""}>
            {applicant.user.name}
        </td>
        <td>{applicant.user.email}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
}
return iter;
```

}

CSS:

```
.no-border-top {
    border-top: none;
}
```

You can also use inline styling like so:

```
renderTableRows() {
const iter = [];
const noBorderTopStyle = {
    borderTop: "none"
}

if (this.props.waitList !== null) {
  this.props.waitList.map((applicant, index) => {
    iter.push(
      <tr>
        <td style={index === 0 ? noBorderTopStyle : null}>
            {applicant.user.name}
        </td>
        <td>{applicant.user.email}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
}
return iter;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use first-child selector on your `tr` as follows:

```
tbody tr:first-child td{ 
    border-top:0;
}
```